# C# sharepoint adding extra semicolon

Tags: c#, html, sharepoint, encode

So I've got a Sharepoint site at the company I'm working for. I've been building C# windows services to extract data from various sources and update the Sharepoint data as needed. I have a copy of the data within my SQL Server database.

This is a two way communication between Sharepoint and my database. I download the data from Sharepoint and update my database as need, and from the other sources I also update my database and also push these changes to my Sharepoint.

This all works fine for the fields in question. However I need to test this on a test system and not the LIVE Sharepoint.

1) I don't have permission's to copy a sharepoint site.
2) No one on the team has permissions.

So, I extracted the data from Sharepoint to excel and was able to get the column names. I build a test Sharepoint site which mimics the LIVE Sharepoint site.
So now I download all the data from the Live Sharepoint and then I push this data to the TEST Sharepoint.

The problem is the data is being altered when I push it back to my TEST Sharepoint.

For example, there is a column called Comments which is multiple lines of text.
And in the comments you have something like the following

`Sent email to following people Person One <person.one@comp.com>;Person Two <person.two@comp.com>;Person Three <person.three@comp.com>`

This downloads fine to my database and I see the following text in my row.

But then I push this data to my TEST Sharepoint and it did the following

`Sent email to following people Person One ;Person Two ;Person Three`

So now I call HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(db.Comments)
And I step through code and look at the data in debug prior to it being sent to  Sharepoint, and this is what is created and sent;

`Sent email to following people Person One &lt;person.one@comp.com&gt;;Person Two &lt;person.two@comp.com&gt;;Person Three &lt;person.three@comp.com&gt;`

But when I look in Sharepoint now at my data I see the following;

`Sent email to following people Person One <person.one@comp.com>;;Person Two <person.two@comp.com>;;Person Three <person.three@comp.com>;`

Extra semicolon at the end of each email within the <>

I don't know how to resolve this since I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary. I step through code and everything looks fine in debug

Thanks
Joe

Comment: show some code. it's really hard to suggest anything without the code

Comment: You must consider the sharepoint service pack level of the two server. From  version to another can (dramatically..) change how data are managed. I hope you use the Sharepoint Services to upload data. Consider also to use SSIS for merge/align Sharepoint vs SQL Server (much simpler...)

Comment: Note:
The SharePoint multiline-text column have two options: [Plain Text and Rich Text](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7), and the question: at SharePoint TEST environment, this multiline-text is Plain Text or Rich Text?